# I need an authentication / identity server

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

We need a new authentication server for our large business system (ERP). The previous authentication server was internally developed. Now that we need a new one we will first try to find an already existing authentication server that we can use. Can anyone recommend an authentication server? Remember that this is a business system, so things like Facebook login is not an option. Do microsoft / google or others have any authentication servers that can be installed and run locally?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to store the usernames in your DB, because you do not want to be dependent on 3rd party to store them for you. Furthermore, you do not want to force your users to have accounts in the 3rd party (e.g. Facebook, Google).

So AFAIK, the only option for you is to maintain your own authentication-server...

The good news: you have oauth-2 packages that you can use, and I've written [a project that implements all authentication-server flows](https://github.com/OhadR/oauth2-sample), such as registration, forgot password, etc.

You can [see a demo here](http://auth-flows-demo.appspot.com/).

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your oauth-2 project looks good. You are right that I need to host my own authentication-server, but I was hoping to find an authentication server that was already built and ready, and I would just provide it with usernames and passwords.

Comment: I'm afraid there is none... maybe the closest thing is Spring CAS. Yet, you will have tom implement your own server.

Comment: ...and don't forget to mark my answer as "correct" (if it helped you :) )